# SQL - Avoiding a Union All

Tags: sql

I have 2 databases: items (With ID and Name) and countries (with ID and Country Name).  I'm looking for a query that lists all items without the country blank as well as each item with the matching country.  Example:

```
ItemID ItemName
1      Item1
2      Item2

ItemID Country
1      US
1      Canada
```

Desired Output:

```
ItemID ItemName Country
1      Item1    NULL
1      Item1    US
1      Item1    Canada
2      Item2    NULL
```

Without the first line, it's just a simple join:

```
SELECT
     i.[ItemID]
     ,i.[ItemName]
     ,ic.[Country]
 FROM ItemCountry ic
    INNER JOIN Item i ON ic.ItemID = i.ItemID
```

However, the only way I've figured out to get the first line to appear is by doing a union:

```
SELECT
     i.[ItemID]
     ,i.[ItemName]
     ,ic.[Country]
 FROM ItemCountry ic
    INNER JOIN Item i ON ic.ItemID = i.ItemID
UNION all
SELECT
     i.[ItemID]
     ,i.[ItemName]
     ,NULL
```

I would like to avoid a union as the databases are large and I plan on filtering out a subset after I have the full list but I don't know if it's possible.

The filtering is for selecting the items on page #X, so it can't be done until I have the full (ordered) list.

Comment: What is the problem with union ? You can filter the union result.

Comment: The problem with union is that the databases can be large and I don't want to expand either one until after the filtering.

Comment: Then explain the filtering, maybe we can help if understand the full picture.

Comment: The filtering is just a .Skip((Page#-1)*PageSize).Take(PageSize).  I don't think it really matters other than the fact that avoiding a union wouldn't matter if I was going to return the whole query anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the union as a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT
             i.[ItemID]
             ,i.[ItemName]
             ,ic.[Country]
        FROM ItemCountry ic
        FULL JOIN Item i ON ic.ItemID = i.ItemID
        UNION all
        SELECT
             i.[ItemID]
             ,i.[ItemName]
             ,NULL
      ) as T
WHERE <something> 
ORDER BY <T.someField>
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in the question: I know how to do the filtering afterwards. I'm trying to avoid having to run the union and enumerate everything before doing the filtering (the databases are large enough that it matters).

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `INNER JOIN` and `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT i.ItemID, i.ItemName, ic.Country
FROM ItemCountry ic JOIN
     Item i
     ON ic.ItemID = i.ItemID
UNION ALL
SELECT i.ItemID, i.ItemName, NULL
FROM Item i;
```

I think this is the simplest way.  I wouldn't use `FULL JOIN` when `INNER JOIN` is appropriate.

Comment: Good catch. I'll correct that line.  So you're saying you don't think there's a way to do it without the UNION?